# Exactly one pair in Prolog list

Tags: list, prolog

Does anybody know how I can go about determining/ensuring that there is exactly one duplicate element in a prolog list?

I am studying for a test.

Comment: I have written a method called count(X,Y,Z), which binds Z to the number of times X occurs in the list Y. I am trying to work off that but I am not sure which direction to go in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort the list using `sort/2`. It removes duplicates, so if the sorted list is exactly one shorter, you had exactly one pair.

```
one_duplicate(L) :-
    sort(L, Sorted),
    length(L, Len),
    length(Sorted, SortedLen),
    Len =:= SortedLen + 1.
```

Finding the duplicate pair is another question altogether.

Comment: Nice! I have an urge to put sort/2 last, even, if this would not improve the program.

Comment: @false I thought about it. I wrote the code after I wrote the free text, so hence the order. It would also make it necessary to use `is` or `succ` for the length of _SortedLen_ and that feels a bit strange.

Comment: The biggest downside of putting sort/2 last, would be that there is no longer a clean instantiation error for a partial list. Think of `one_duplicate(L)` or `one_duplicate([a|L])`.

Answer (score -2):

```
one_duplicate(L) :-
    sort(L, Sorted),
    length(L, Len),
    length(Sorted, SortedLen),
    Len =:= SortedLen + 1.
```